# Install a Program from ZIP File on Ubuntu Not Found Using Aptitude

Tags: linux, installation, shell, zip

I have a specific program that I use often on Windows and Mac, but today need to install it on a Linux machine.  I downloaded the ZIP file from the vendors website, unzipped it to the Desktop and now I have an SH file.  I tried running this file from the command line as root, but the permissions were denied.

How can I install this program on Linux?  I know it's possible because I have heard of it being done.  I just don't have the experience with Linux I need to get it done.  To which directory should I install it?  I tried the install command but it needed a directory to which to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the SH file is executable:

```
chmod +x myfile.sh
```

Run that as root, then you should be able to run the SH as root.